# jQuery find text string and add class

Tags: jquery, addclass

ok I am trying to find the text strings of certain users, such as TheGamer, runawayhorses, and so forth. And when the code finds these text strings in the td> it will add the class to change the background color of it... Its giving me alot of issues.

```
$(window).ready(function () {
$('.post > span > a:contains("TheGamer,runawayhorses")').next('tr').parent('tr').addClass      ('manager');
});
```

Generated HTML=

```
<tbody>
<tr align="right">
<tr>
<tr class="post">
<td class="row1" width="150" valign="top">
<span class="name">
<strong>
<a href="/u1">
<span style="color:#09B300">
<strong>TheGamer</strong>
</span>
</a>
</strong>
</span>
<br>
<span class="gensmall toggle" style="cursor:pointer;">View More</span>
<div id="hidden" class="hidden" style="padding: 1px; width: 150px; height: 50px; background: none repeat scroll 0% 0% rgb(196, 196, 196); border: 3px solid rgb(0, 0, 0); position: absolute; z-index: 999; display: none;">
<span class="postdetails poster-profile"></span>
<br>
<span>Admin</span>
<br>
<span>
<span style="white-space:nowrap;">
<img title="" alt="" src="http://i45.servimg.com/u/f45/17/65/32/03/title113.gif">
<span style="white-space:nowrap;">
10
<br>
<span style="white-space:nowrap;">
20
 <br>
 <span style="white-space:nowrap;">
  2012-07-10
<br>
<span style="white-space:nowrap;">
23
 <br>
 <span style="white-space:nowrap;">
New York
 <br>
 <br>
 <img style="width:150px;height:1px" alt="" src="http://illiweb.com/fa/empty.gif">
 </td>
 <td class="row1" width="100%" valign="top" height="28" colspan="2">
 </tr>
 <tr>
 <tr class="post">
 <td class="row2" width="150" valign="top">
 <span class="name">
 <strong>
 <a href="/u3">
 <span style="color:#09B300">
  <strong>NOT USERS</strong>
 </span>
 </a>
 </strong>
 </span>
 <br>
  <span class="gensmall toggle" style="cursor:pointer;">View More</span>
```

What the generated HMTL is showing, is that the tr with the class of post should change background color to what I would like. .row1 and .row2 already have background colors, so I believe my CSS would have to have a !important after the color...

Any suggestions or examples please. I don't want to change all the tr's in the field, just the ones with the text strings I gave. Reason I can't just go into the generated HTML is because this is a forum board, and the information below is parsed by php placeholders. thats the reason i need jQuery

Comment: I'm trying to understand structure of your markup.

Comment: Its a little messed up :( but basically, trying to find TheGamer in a TR and use jQuery to addClass to the TD inside the TR. The TD already has a class named row1 or row2, with backgrounds set. Im trying to make it so that it is more visible to users to know its a moderator. I'm sorry for the lack of explanation its kind of hard to explain.

Comment: You can view the website here    http://thegamerspodium.forumotion.com/t3-hey-ya-all 

to see the html better, and see what I'm trying to do kind of. None of the colors that i want are up since I can't figure it out

Comment: I figured it out for the most part. If someone could help me with the rest? It makes the background of the first td have the class, but how do you make the td next to it have the class as well?

$(document).ready(function() { 
    var $a = $('.post td span a'); 
    $a.filter(':contains("TheGamer")').closest('td').removeClass('row1').addClass('manager'); 
   });

Comment: nevermind I got it by using .next :) nevermind people